# Read Raw USB Input on Windows

Tags: windows, usb, hid

I have device that is a USB HID Human Interface that sends keycodes to usb host when I press the keys and I just can't find **a simple program that will dump all the input data that comes in my USB port?** (with source code available of course. USBlyzer does it, but it's shareware)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [libusb](https://libusb.info/) and [#USBLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpusblib/) Both are open sourse. #USBLib is a .net wrapper around the multi platform libusb.

Comment: i have looked at them, but could'nt find out a working example. on msdn there are also parts of example on "Using Raw Input". damn couldn't they do a normal example from start to end?!!

Comment: yes i've got it working, but not as expected. see my other question