# Select specific USB keyboard input device?

Tags: c++, keyboard, usb

I am working on a small project: I need to take the input from a number pad and run macros based off which key was pressed. However, I'm having some difficulty reading from the number pad specifically. `stdin` simply reads from the key inputs; I actually need the raw data output from the number pad USB device. The number pad is a **separate device** from the keyboard.

My research indicates I'll have to write a device driver for it using the `Windows DDK`, but this doesn't quite make sense to me. I want to select a different USB input device as a keyboard - this shouldn't require a new driver, as I'll still be using it as a keyboard. I just need to change the scope of my input stream to just the USB device.

I could also be missing some key piece of information. So, is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373247/read-raw-usb-input-on-windows

Comment: Post as answer for accept.

Comment: If memory serves, you can use DirectInput on Windows to read from a specific keyboard. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee417799%28v=VS.85%29.aspx  YMMV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read the RAW usb-events from the right device. You can write that code either yourself by reading '[Raw Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645536%28VS.85%29.aspx)' or '[Human Interface Devices Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff539956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)' (part of the Windows Driver Kit) on MSDN.

Or you could use [libusb](https://libusb.info/), as mentioned on [Read Raw USB Input on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373247/read-raw-usb-input-on-windows), which hides a lot of the crufty details under a neat API. A rough idea is to:

- get the list of devices via `libusb_get_device_list()`
- find the keyboard you are interested in via `libusb_get_device_descriptor()`, check the `examples/listdevs.c` file for a clue about how to do that.
- open the device via `libusb_open()`
- do your magic (i think polling for events will fit)
- and .. close the device at the end

Side note: libusb flawlessly built on Windows8 with VS2012 Express + WDK8.

Comment: What do you mean by polling for events? I cannot cast a C++ pointer to libusb_device_handle to a pointer to HRAWINPUT. Thank you.